# Parsing through Array of multidimensional arrays JS and logging the indecies

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have three multidimensional arrays. The function findIndex, will go through one of the arrays, if I set the last line to findIndex(arrayTwo), and spit out the item and index variable telling me where the variable idName is.

Example: if I call findIndex(arrayTwo), it will console log item: 2 | index: 1
http://jsfiddle.net/vap03jfL/

The problem is that when i run the function findIndex(arrayCombine) it will only search through the first two levels of the new array set. I know I need to search one level deeper and return a value for the now top most array, but I haven't found what I need.  I have also read that the way I am doing this may not be the best. to begin with.

```
var arrayOne = [
    ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    ["e", "f", "g", "h"],
    ["i", "j", "k", "l"],
    ["m", "n", "o", "p"]
];

var arrayTwo = [
    ["Z1", "Y1", "X2", "W2"],
    ["V2", "U3", "T3", "S3"],
    ["R3", "Q3", "P3", "O3"],
    ["N4", "M2", "L2", "K2"]
];

var arrayThree = [
    ["Z", "Y", "X", "W"],
    ["V", "U", "T", "S"],
    ["R", "Q", "P", "O"],
    ["N", "M", "L", "K"]
];

var arrayCombine = [
    [arrayOne],
    [arrayTwo],
    [arrayThree]
]


function findIndex(arrayArg) {
    idName = "Q3";

    for (var item in arrayArg) {
        console.log("item: " + item);
        if (arrayArg[item].indexOf(idName)) {
            var index = arrayArg[item].indexOf(idName);
            console.log("index: " + index);
            if (index != -1) {
                console.log("item found: " + item);
                console.log("index found: " + index);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

findIndex(arrayCombine);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I should clarify a bit... Currently changing the function call at the bottom to findIndex(arrayTwo) and still searching for "Q3"  the output matches the expected location in the array.

"item found: 2" | "index found: 1" 


With calling findIndex(arrayCombine) I am looking for an output of say 

"array: 1" | "item found: 2" | "index found: 1" 

This way I can use these variables and plug them into another function elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I came up with.
http://jsfiddle.net/vap03jfL/7/

Problem 1: the nested array was written incorrectly, I shouldn't have bracketed the variable being called in the nested array, it should have been written.

```
var arrayCombine = [arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree];
```

Problem 2: I needed to parse another level.. this is a slightly different strategy but works with jagged arrays too.

function findIndex(arrayArg) {
    idName = "Q3";

```
for (var arrayId = 0; arrayId < arrayArg.length; arrayId++) {
    for (var item = 0; item < arrayArg[arrayId].length; item++) {
        var index = arrayArg[arrayId][item].indexOf(idName);
        if (index >= 0) {
            console.log("arrayId " + arrayId + " | item: " + item + " | Found Index! " + index);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your function recursive to handle a deep search.

```
function findIndex(arrayArg, idName) {

    for (var item in arrayArg) {
        if (typeof arrayArg[item] == "object" && arrayArg[item] != null) {
            if (findIndex(arrayArg[item], idName)) {
                return true
            }
        } else {
            var index = arrayArg[item].indexOf(idName)
            if (index != -1) {
                console.log("item found: " + item);
                console.log("index found: " + index);
                return true;
            } else { 
                console.log(arrayArg[item] + " != " + idName);
            }        
        }
    }
    return false;
}

findIndex(arrayCombine, "Q3");
```

Instead of nesting if statements inside of loops inside of if statements, you can use the power of recursivity to do a deep search with no upper limit on the number of nested arrays or objects you are permitted to scan.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts but when I tried this in the fiddle it wasn't working for me.. Not sure what I was missing but I posted my solution in a fiddle below.

Comment: Hmm. I just ran it and it did exactly what I said it would do: https://jsfiddle.net/maapxgoL/1/. The only issue I can see is that it console-logs the index of the array item rather than the string--I edited so that it console logs the name of the item, too. Your solution, while workable for the specific problem isn't able to tackle deeply nested arrays (like the one you originally posted). As a programmer you should strive to make reusable code that can be reapplied when the magnitude and nature of your input changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findIndex(arrayArg, idName) {
    for (var i in arrayArg) {
        console.log("item: " + item);
        var item = arrayArg[i];
        if(item instanceof Array) {
            if(findIndex(item, idName)) {
               return true;
            }
        } else if (item.indexOf(idName)) {
            var index = item.indexOf(idName);
            console.log("index: " + index);
            if (index != -1) {
                console.log("item found: " + item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function will return prematurely if the searched id isn't in the first array  you hit in the loop. Furthermore, there is no condition returning from findIndex that will indicate whether or not the search was successful.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts but when I tried this in the fiddle it wasn't working for me.. Not sure what I was missing but I posted my solution in a fiddle below.